# Maven profiles: maven-antrun-plugin & maven-war-plugin interaction

Tags: maven, maven-profiles, maven-antrun-plugin

I have a `Spring framework` project with the following three files in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`:

```
project.propterties
project-servlet.xml
project-security.xml
```

I am trying to use `maven profiles` as follows to 'inject' the above mentioned files in the case of a `prod` build:

```
        <profile>
        <id>prod-build</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <delete
                                        file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/project.properties" />
                                    <copy file="src/main/config/prod/project.properties"
                                        tofile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/project.properties" />
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/prod</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

The problem is by the time `maven-antrun-plugin` gets a chance to run, the `war` has already been packaged. The ant `<target>` does run and makes appropriate changes, but too late.

The command line:

```
$ mvn -Pprod-build clean install
```

mvn output:

```
    [INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) @ FocusMVN ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to J:\work\workspace\FocusMVN\target\myproject\WEB-INF
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) @ FocusMVN ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [FocusMVN] in [J:\work\workspace\FocusMVN\target\myproject]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [J:\work\workspace\FocusMVN\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [3198 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: J:\work\workspace\FocusMVN\target\myproject.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ FocusMVN ---
[INFO] Installing J:\work\workspace\FocusMVN\target\myproject.war to C:\Users\mansoork\.m2\repository\ca\utoronto\med\dc\FocusMVN\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\FocusMVN-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing J:\work\workspace\FocusMVN\pom.xml to C:\Users\mansoork\.m2\repository\ca\utoronto\med\dc\FocusMVN\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\FocusMVN-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can bind `antrun` to `prepare-package` phase instead of `package` one.

Comment: @Andrew Logvinov Thanks; It doesn't appear to make a difference; I have updated my question with mvn output, can you please take a look?

Comment: Which maven version do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I'm using  Maven 3.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you note this line

```
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [J:\work\workspace\FocusMVN\src\main\webapp]
```

What's going on ?

The `maven-war-plugin` copy the content of `src/main/webapp` (which contains your *dev* `project.properties`) to the war. And while doing this it replace the one just copied by the ant task.

What you can try is to exclude the `project.properties` from the fileset copied by the maven-war-plugin (since it was already copied by your ant task.)

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>     
    <configuration>
       <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/project.propterties</warSourceExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

[reference](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceExcludes)

Comment: You mean warSourceExcludes?

Answer (score 1):

In the *phase* use *prepare-package* instead of *package*.

Instead of *maven-antrun-plugin* try to use *copy-maven-plugin*

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.goldin</groupId>
            <artifactId>copy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-archive</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                            <targetPath>${basedir}/target/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/project*</include>
                            </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: +1: You beat me to it! :) In addition, have a look at the list of phases described here: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-structure.html .

Comment: @Carlos Rodrigues thanks for your comment. I have updated my question with mvn output, using prepare-package didn't help either. Can you please take a look? Thank you.